# Are there some formulae in facial recognition that are indicators of close kinship?

Tags: machine-learning, facial-recognition

I noticed what I considered a close resemblance of a woman B to another woman A which led to a close relative A labelled C, who B bore an even stronger resemblance to than she did to A.

However I feel that if I had compared A to C directly I wouldn't have detected the blood relationship so strongly.

I am just wondering whether there is some mathematical underpinning to my perception and strong intuition that B bore a strong resemblance to A.

Comment: please ask your question is a *WAY* less scrambled manner

Comment: How do you characterise less scrambled? This is not an area I am familiar with so I am not quite sure of what terminology to use. I could use pictures to describe it, but has it has interracial dimension that is likely to derail the threadbut I want to be sure that some mathematics exists along such lines before prejudicing the response

Comment: @mshlis Feel free to edit it in accord with a more "scientific" way if you understand the question well enough